# I cannot access drawable .png

Tags: android

I am in trouble how can I access the drawable icons.png inside in the drawable folder (-hdpi,-mdpi,-xhdpi,-xxhdpi,-xxxhdpi) ?. because I want to place it to my listview. I am using api 23

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private String somevar;

 Integer[] myImg= {
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.)//it's not recognizing.


    };

     ....
      ....
}
```

[image]

Comment: i think it will achieve using getIdentifier() try this link : .http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: Try getting the `drawable-?` folders out of `drawable`, as a direct child of `res`. Also, make `drawable` a separate folder - also a child of `res`, and put a copy of the images (the size you want) inside it. See structure here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

Comment: so I make a copy of my icons under my drawable folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an `Integer array`, pass the resource ids instead of passing the drawable objects. Otherwise use an array of drawables instead.

Comment: I'm still new with this, where i can find the resource ids ?

Comment: You use them as R.drawable.yourImageName

Comment: No, like this: Integer[] myImg= {
    R.drawable.yourImageName, ... }; for an Integer Array and like this: Drawable[] myImg= {
    ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.yourImageName), ..}; for a drawable array.

Comment: I cannot access the image or my .png because they are inside in each different folder -hdpi,xhdpi,-xxhdpi,-xxxhdpi..

Comment: Do I need to use the drawable array ?

Comment: They should  be accessible even then. "Do I need to use the drawable array ?"  That depends on your needs.

Comment: @jemz Using the integer array is better, for memory usage. If you specify the ID, the device will select the correct resource size.

Comment: @Doomsknight ContextCompat.getDrawable() also gets you the drawable with the correct size.

Comment: Depending on usage, you may not want to load 30+ image into memory. If only one is displayed at a time. for example.

Answer (score 1):

Convert `Integer` array

```
Integer[] myImg= {
ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.)//it's not recognizing.
};
```

to `Drawable` array:

```
Drawable[] myImg= {
    ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.)//Now it will recognize it.
};
```

Comment: It recognize but I want to use Integer

Comment: ContextCompat.getDrawable(); function returns Drawable. what you want to do with integer[] ? 
an other getResources.getDrawable(R.drawabl.) is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

First check if your *.png exist in project, then rebuild your project.

If u want use IntegerArray then:

```
Integer[] myImg= {
    R.drawable.yourImageName1,
    R.drawable.yourImageName2
    ....
};
```

`R.drawable.yourImageName1` is an Integer.

`~.getDrawable(..);` returns Drawable.